# Webpack - devServer.watchFiles breaks Hot Module Replacement (HMR) in webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

I'm following a Udemy course and trying to get HMR running with webpack version 5.67.0 and webpack-dev-server 4.7.3, but it does not work. When I modify and save a CSS file, webpack re-compiles the project correctly, and the front-end updates correctly, but ***hot module replacement*** doesn't work. It does a full page reload instead. HMR *was working fine* until I tried to implement the `before` property.

I have been down a rabbit hole for two days following different suggestions, but still it is not working.

Here is my **webpack.config.js**:

```js
const path = require('path')

const postCSSPlugins = [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('autoprefixer')
]

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/assets/scripts/App.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundled.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
    },
    devServer: {
        watchFiles: ('./app/**/*.html'),
        static: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
        hot: true,
        port: 3000,
        // liveReload: false
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader', {loader: "postcss-loader", options: {postcssOptions: {plugins: postCSSPlugins}}}]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### DETAILED PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:

Here are the details:

1. Hot module reload was working until I tried to add the `devServer.before` property in webpack.config.js

**devServer** property:

```
devServer: {
  before: function(app, server) {
   server._watch('./app/**/*.html')
  },
  static: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  hot: true,
  port: 3000
},
```

and my **App.js** file:

```
import '../styles/styles.css';

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
}
```

2. When I tried to add the `before` property I got the error that this property was invalid also. I found this migration guide (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md) saying that `before` was replaced with `onBeforeSetupMiddleware` and arguments were changed also. I tried replacing before with this:

**onBeforeSetupMiddleware** property:

```
onBeforeSetupMiddleware: function (devServer) {
   devServer.app.get('./app/**/*.html', function (req, res) {
     res.json({ custom: "response" });
   });
},
```

3. At that point there were no more compile errors for the server, but ***hot reload wasn't working anymore***. Whenever I changed the CSS it did a FULL PAGE RELOAD every time!
4. Then I spent another half hour combing the course Q&A for answers. I found one user, Simeon who said this:

> For those who are using Webpack 5 and webpack-dev-server >= 4.0.0.
>
> In webpack.config.js change before option with the following:
>
> watchFiles: ('./app/**/*.html'),

5. So, I removed onBeforeSetupMiddleware and replaced with `watchFiles`. Restarted the dev server. NO CHANGE --whenever CSS is changed it does a full page refresh now!

Help! What am I doing wrong? How can I get this fixed?

Thank you!

PS: If it helps, here's my GitHub repo where you can see my all my code:

- https://github.com/codewizard13/travel-site/tree/ERROR_HotReload